# viewForFooterInSection Not Called with Cell Constraints Broken

Tags: ios, uitableview, autolayout

I am using [SWTableViewCell](https://github.com/CEWendel/SWTableViewCell) library for displaying cells. I want to add a footerview to the section. Problem is that, when I add footer with following two delegate methods, cells constraints are broken.

```
-(UIView *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 20)];
    footerView.backgroundColor = FOOTER_BACKGROUND_COLOR;

    CGRect newframe = footerView.frame;
    newframe.size.height = self.parentView.frame.size.height - 65 - [self heightForTotalCells];
    footerView.frame = newframe;
    return footerView;
}

-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    CGFloat totCellsHeight = [self heightForTotalCells];
    return self.parentView.frame.size.height - 65 - totCellsHeight;
}
```

I placed breakpoints and checked that only `heightForFooterInSection` is being called. `viewForFooterInSection` is not invoked.

If I use `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection` and remove `heightForFooterInSection`, constraints stop breaking, and the `estimatedHeightForFooterInSection` is invoked as well, but strangely, `viewForFooterInSection` isn't been called still.

```
-(CGFloat) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView estimatedHeightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
}
```

Can someone please help me to sort out problem or point towards debugging steps? Thanks.

Comment: not sure but if heightForFooterInSection returns 0 then viewForFooterInSection is not called

Comment: also if you are using autolayout, don't change frame directly, use constraints

Comment: Check delegate connection in StoryBoard